# How can I abort the delivery of an ActionMailer request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm running a Q&A service. One of the things admins can do is mark a question as offtopic. When they they do that an email gets sent to the person that asked the question telling them that their email is offtopic.

The email notification is sent via delayed_job:

```
QuestionMailer.delay.notify_asker_of_offtopic_flag question
```

However, on occasion someone might accidentally mark the question as offtopic or change their mind. To avoid an incorrect notification going to the person who originally asked it I want to create a short delay and evaluate whether the question is still offtopic when the mailer request runs:

*Delayed call to mailer:*

```
QuestionMailer.delay(run_at: Time.now + 3.minutes).notify_asker_of_offtopic_flag(question)
```

*Mailer:*

```
class QuestionMailer
  ...
  def notify_asker_of_offtopic_flag question
     if question.offtopic?
       # do mailing
     end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately this isn't that simple since the `if` block simply causes an error which then causes delayed_job to retry the job again and again.

I'm now experimenting with some pretty roundabout methods to achieve the same end but I'd really like to find some way to abort the `QuestionMailer` action without triggering errors. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aditya's answer was basically correct however I wanted to keep my methods on the Mailer object to keep things nice and tidy. This required a few extra hacks.

**Create a new Class method in the mailer that CAN be delayed**

The problem with trying to cancel an instance Mailer method is that it inherently triggers rendering and other things that stop the method from being aborted. However I would still like to keep all my Mailer logic together.

The way I did this was by using a class method instead of an instance method. This avoided all of the hooks that kick in when calling the method on an `ActionMailer` instance but still allowed me to keep the code tidy and together

```
class QuestionMailer
  ...
  def notify_asker_of_offtopic_flag question
    ...
  end

  def self.notify_asker_of_offtopic_flag question_if question
    if question.offtopic?
      QuestionMailer.notify_asker_of_offtopic_flag question
    end
  end
end
```

**NB fix for using delayed job**

This works except for one slight hack that's necessary to deal with `delayed_job`.

When dealing with a Mailer, delayed_job will always call `.deliver` on the returned object in order to deliver the mail. This is fine when we return a mail object but in this case we're returning nil. `delayed_job` therefore tries to call `.deliver` on `nil`  and everything fails.

In order to account for this we simply return a dummy mailer object containing a dupe `.deliver` method:

```
class QuestionMailer
  ...
  class DummyMailer
    def deliver
      return true
    end
  end

  def notify_asker_of_offtopic_flag question
    # do mailing stuff
  end

  def self.notify_asker_of_offtopic_flag question_if question
    if question.offtopic?
      QuestionMailer.notify_asker_of_offtopic_flag question
    else
      DummyMailer.new
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont delay the mailer then. Delay another class method in your Question class perhaps? Pass the id of the question and within that delayed method check if the question is still offtopic and if yes the send email synchronously.

Essentially, your notify_asker_of_offtopic_flag could be moved to your question model and then mailing is synchronous (i'm sure you'll rename your methods).

There is talk going on about preventing delivering by setting perform_deliveries to false within your mail action itself in core but i'm not 100% where or how that will end up.

Comment: Thanks for that, very helpful. It was where I was considering going but wasn't sure if there was a cleaner way